# OpenModelica - Model hardstops in custom block

Tags: openmodelica

In OpenModelica, i want to customize the behavior of a spring mechanism and use this to determine the position of a prismatic joint. The behavior can be seen as a pre-loaded spring with hard stops. When a force is applied to the mechanism, and the force is lower than the pre-load force, the displacement is zero and the force is transfered rigidly. If a force higher than the pre-load force is applied, the spring moves until it hits a hard stop. When moving, the displacement is found with the spring constant. When the hardstop is hit, the force is transferred rigidly again. This can be summarised with the following if-statement:

```
if F_in < F_preload
  s = 0;
  f = Fin;
elseif (F_in-F_preload)/k < LimUp then
  s = (F_in-F_preload)/k ;
  f = 0;
else
  s = LimUp;
  f = F_in - k*Lim - F_preload;  
end if;
```

A custom block has been made with this if-statement as the basis of it. I looked into the (instantiated) code of 'Spring', 'ElastoGap' and 'MassWithStopAndFriction'. However when I run my code it is said to be overdetermined.
This is probably due to the positions of the flanges being defined multiple times.
What can i do to solve this, or what what would be another way to add hardstops in OpenModelica?

The code for my custom block can be seen below:

```
block ElastoGapTest
extends Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.PartialCompliant;  
import Modelica.Units.SI;

// Parameters
parameter SI.TranslationalSpringConstant c(min=0, start=100) "Spring constant";
parameter SI.TranslationalDampingConstant d(min=0, start=1) "Damping constant";  
parameter SI.Position s_rel0 = 0 "Unstretched spring length";
constant Real LimUp = 0.1;
constant Real FVoor = 1000;

// Variables
Real Fin;
Real FLim;
Real f;
Real s_tijd;
Real s;

 equation
// Input force
Fin = flange_a.f;
FLim = c * LimUp;
s_tijd = (abs(Fin) - FVoor) / c;

// Conditional logic
if abs(Fin) < FVoor then
s = 0;
f = Fin;
  elseif s_tijd < LimUp then
s = s_tijd;
f = 0;
else
s = LimUp;
f = abs(Fin) - FLim - FVoor;  
end if;

// Negative if negative input
if Fin < 0 then
s = -s;
f = -f;
end if;

end ElastoGapTest;
```

My custom block is used in the following code:

```
model TestModel
  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world 
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Revolute revolute 
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body body(m = 10) 
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyBox bodyBox(r = {1, 0, 0})  
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Prismatic prismatic(useAxisFlange = true)  
  ElastoGapTest elastoGapTest
equation
  connect(world.frame_b, revolute.frame_a)
  connect(bodyBox.frame_a, revolute.frame_b)
  connect(prismatic.frame_b, body.frame_a)
  connect(prismatic.frame_a, bodyBox.frame_b)
  connect(prismatic.support, elastoGapTest.flange_a)
  connect(prismatic.axis, elastoGapTest.flange_b)
end TestModel;
```